# jQuery.ajax not working

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

So my js:

```
$('#introorderbtn').click(function () {
    var display = document.getElementById("display").value;
    var skype = document.getElementById("skype").value;
    var music = document.getElementById("music").value;
    var ideas = document.getElementById("ideas").value;

    $.post('php/intro.php',{id:ID,gname:gname,name:Name,email:email,display:display,skype:skype,music:music,ideas:ideas}, function(data) {

    });

    jQuery.ajax({
        url: 'php/file.php',
        type: 'post',
        data: {id:ID,gname:gname,name:Name,email:email,display:display,skype:skype,music:music,ideas:ideas},
        success: function(data){
            $('#results').html(data);
            $('#display').val = "";
            $('#skype').val = "";
            $('#music').val = "";
            $('#ideas').val = "";
        }
    });

});
```

And my HTML

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div style="display = none" id="gal">
        <h1>Order a free Introduction</h1>
        <p>This is a 2D Intro: about 7 sec. long and choisable with an alpha-transition (so called "Opener").<br>They are in 1920x1080px and 60fps of course!<br> Most clients picked this product, do it like them!<br> When you are not sure about my art, take a look into the Gallery.</p>
        <form>
            <h1>Gimme some Data:</h1>
            <input id="display" type="text" placeholder="Name Displayed in the Intro">
            <input id="skype" type="text" placeholder="Your Skype ID">
            <input id="music" type="url" placeholder="Music (No Dubstep Trap stuff pls)">
            <textarea id="ideas" placeholder="Your Ideas: "></textarea>
            <input type="submit" id="introorderbtn">
        </form>
        <div id="results"></div>
```

Here my php

```
<?php
$id = $_POST['id'];
$gname = $_POST['gname'];
$name = $_POST['name'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$display = $_POST['display'];
$skype = $_POST['skype'];
$music = $_POST['music'];
$ideas = $_POST['ideas'];

echo("Test");
---msql connection that works 100%---
?>
```

The php works alone w/o problems, but when I'm trying to post the data from the form and some more strings from other scripts it doesn't.
The success function is working, but it doesn't show the result.

Comment: Are there any errors on the console? Did you check the network tab if the server actually responded? Did you add a breakpoint in `success` to check what `data`'s value is?

Comment: Posting a jsbin or jsfiddle always helps.

Comment: $('introorderbtn') is not ever going to return anything.  Consequently, the behavior you have set up won't ever be triggered.  You need to change it to:

$('#introorderbtn')

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first issue I see is

```
dataType: JSON,
```

which should be

```
dataType: 'JSON',
```

or just leave it off, as jQuery should be able to figure it out automatically.

Also, I think you will need to change

```
$('#results').html(data);
```

to:

```
$('#results').html(JSON.stringify(data));
```

or to something that is not an object, at least.

This is assuming, of course, that `data` is in fact coming back as `json`, as you indicated.

Comment: php is responding with echo(...)

Comment: if your dataType isn't json, why do you have `dataType: JSON`?  That is not correct, and a likely cause of the issue.  It should either be `dataType: 'text'` or `dataType: 'html'`